# How to jump to the next input field after user selection on a typeahead

Tags: angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui-typeahead

I have a form that some autocompletes (using angular-ui boostrap typeaheade) and some plain input elements. Whenever the user chooses from the typeahead (via tab, enter, or mouse click), I want the focus to move onto the next form field. Instead, they have to hit tab/enter twice, once to select, and a second time to jump to the next field.

In version 0.6.0 of ui-bootstrap, I could achieve this by using typeahead-on-select to call a function like

```
$scope.onSelect = function() {
    $timeout(function() {
        // code involving element.closes('form').find('button,input,textarea,select')
    });
}
```

However since upgrading to the current 0.11.2 version of ui-bootstrap, I have to explicitly set a delay on this timeout. On my dev machine, 10ms works, and "feels" fast enough, but this is surely unreliable:

```
$scope.onSelect = function() {
    $timeout(function() {
        // code involving element.closes('form').find('button,input,textarea,select')
    }, 10);
}
```

(I see that the underlying typeahead code started wrapping "element[0].focus()" in a timeout between 0.6.0 and 0.11.2.)

Is there a way to achieve my desired behavior, without an ugly explicit delay on the timeout?